# Workbook sheet date to autofill weekly tracker

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm building an excel workbook in which the first sheet, a user will type a date in A2 and pull down the property he visited in B2. The next sheet is a weekly tracker with the first row labeled weeks 1-52 and the first column labeled by property. What I want to happen: if the date on the first page is entered next to the property, it changes the color of the cell or just puts an x in the cell on the corresponding week/property cell on the next sheet. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you upload your excel sheet and who us what this looks like? It sounds like "conditional formatting"; with conditional formatting you can shade cells any color with given conditions set by you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are possible.

### Put "X":

Use the formula: `=IF(COUNTIFS($C:$C,F$1,$B:$B,$E2)>0,"X","")`

### Highlight cells:

Select your table then go to home - conditional formatting - new rule - use a formula to determine which cells to format.
Here you need just part of the previous formula: `=COUNTIFS($C:$C,F$1,$B:$B,$E2)>0`

[image]